# Taking multiple data units in Adapters getView()

Tags: android, listview

I'm working on list with different layouts. But in one getView call I must consume two elements from data list instead of one. I basically have two different views. In first layout I consume one data element, in second layout I consume three data elements. How should I do it properly ?

Pseudo code:

```
getView()
{
   if(first layout)
   {
      data[position]
      // do the work with it
   }
   if(second layout)
   {
      data[position]
      data[position+1]
      data[position+2]
      // do some work
   }
}
```

Comment: Try to implement getViewType() base adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement every method of your base adapter very carefully. It requires a bit of maths.

Consider your data array is data[] has n number of elements.

You have to make partition of your accordingly.

consider there are 10 elements then following mapping will take place:

data position to list item position :

0 -> 0, 1 -> 1, 2 -> 1, 3 -> 1 .... 8 -> 4, 9 -> 5.

Hence total count of list item will be 6;

So your base adapter should look like this:

```
public class TestAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private static final int VIEW_TYPE_SINGE = 0;
    private static final int VIEW_TYPE_TRIPLE = 1;

    String[] data = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"};

    LayoutInflater inflator;

    public TestAdapter(Context context) {
        this.inflator = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    // Considering your first position use single element and 2nd use triple
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        int count = 0;
        int positionIndex = (data.length - 1) % 4;
        int positionOffset = (data.length - 1) / 4;
        if (positionIndex == 0) {
            count = (2 * positionOffset) + 1;
        } else {
            count = (2 * positionOffset) + 2;
        }
        return count;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return getItemData(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (position % 2 == 0) {
            return VIEW_TYPE_SINGE;
        } else {
            return VIEW_TYPE_TRIPLE;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (getItemViewType(position) == VIEW_TYPE_SINGE) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.test_item_layout_1,
                        null, false);
            }
            String[] data = getItemData(position);
            TextView view = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.one);
            if (data[0] != null)
                view.setText(data[0]);
            return convertView;
        } else {
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.test_item_layout_2,
                        null, false);
            }

            String[] data = getItemData(position);
            TextView view1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.one);
            if (data[0] != null)
                view1.setText(data[0]);

            TextView view2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.two);
            if (data[1] != null)
                view2.setText(data[1]);

            TextView view3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.three);
            if (data[2] != null)
                view3.setText(data[2]);

            return convertView;
        }
    }

    private String[] getItemData(int position) {
        String[] data = null;
        int positionBaseIndex = position / 2 * 4;
        if (getItemViewType(position) == VIEW_TYPE_SINGE) {
            data = new String[1];
            data[0] = this.data[positionBaseIndex];
        } else {
            data = new String[3];
            if (this.data.length > positionBaseIndex + 1)
                data[0] = this.data[positionBaseIndex + 1];
            if (this.data.length > positionBaseIndex + 2)
                data[1] = this.data[positionBaseIndex + 2];
            if (this.data.length > positionBaseIndex + 3)
                data[2] = this.data[positionBaseIndex + 3];
        }
        return data;
    }

}
```

There are many ways of doing so. You can divide your data in two lists in constructor then implement method of base adapter.

Thanks, I hope this will help. :)