# Give a possible way to display data

Tags: android

tell me how best to implement the following representation of information

```
20.10.2014
   7:00 some text
   7:30 some text
   18:00 some text
21.10.2014
   7:20 some text
   7:21 some text
   7:22 some text
22.10.2014
   7:20 some text
```

I know the following solution - ExpandableListView but then the children can curl up. but I do not need or TableLayout with TableRow but I need to fill in the data from the array and implement the click event for each element except the parent.if you ask a stupid question and give direction where to look, I'll delete it

even without the events. usual display of text from a file in a form

Comment: May be a [listview with section headers](https://code.google.com/p/android-amazing-listview/)

Comment: thanks maybe what I need. Now I will understand. if you have other ideas I will be glad to hear

Comment: too beautiful for my problem)))

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:** Use **Multiple Views in ListView**

See this [tutorial](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2014/08/android-listview-with-multiple-row.html) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25738747/2274724) (it is harder one you will need a simple adapter).
It will help you in creating a adapter with two different layouts.

**Option 2:** if you don't want it to be so much complicated use simple base adapter and create a view with both date layout and event layout and change it's visibility.

**Option 3:** In More Simple way create a mutliline text view in scrollView then make your text more formatted using [spannable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html) string.